# How to change the width of TAB character in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

It seems that `EditText` uses only one space character to display a TAB character. How to force it to use two space characters instead?

A TAB character looks in usual (desktop: vim for example) text editors as if there were 2 spaces for example. But from the editing perspective it is still one character. I mean if you have to delete it you still have to delete only one character but not two. Can EditText behave in the same way?

I have tried to find a property like 'tabWidth' in the corresponding part in the layout file, but the only properties that contained 'tab' in their names have been:

`editable` and `textIsSelectable`

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/textArea"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:maxLength="10000000"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:tab...
        />
```

Comment: Can you add a dummy image which can explain what you are looking for?

Comment: I've edited the question. Besides you can read my comment to the first answer. I hope it should be clear now.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution? I ended up with a replacement cycle... seems there is only TabSpan in the beginning of the sentence.

Comment: @MikeMakarov I think I gave up to search for a solution as it wasn't very crucial. My EditText showed some code samples and it would be great to have some indentation. But I could live with it. In worst case you have to pre-process the text and replace all tabs with required number of spaces.

Answer (score -1):

Use TextWatcher

```
textArea.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher{
        override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
             // append whitespace after each character here
             textArea.append(" ")
        }

        override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
        }
    })
```

ps: This is a Kotlin code but you get the idea

Comment: The text shouldn't be changed. Just the tab character should be represented wider than it is now. It should be 2 characters wide, but it doesn't mean that I want to replace each TAB character with 2 space characters. However I don't know whether EditText is capable of doing this.

Comment: for API 21 + there is `android:letterSpacing`